# Laravel - after renaming tables - call to undefined method updateOrCreate()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

After having to rename database tables and running migrations I got:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

For this piece of code:

```
  Shop::updateOrCreate(
    ['id' => $id],
    ['title' => $shopeTitle]
  );

  Mall::where('id', $id)->update([
    'price' => $price,
    'visitors' => $visitors
  ]);

  if ($mall != 41 || $mall!= 42) {
    DB::table('calc_stores_in_malls')->insert([
      'mall' => $price,
      'store' => $id
    ]);
  }
```

Then I have tried with hardcoding new table names like so:

```
     DB::table('calc_shop')->updateOrCreate(
        ['id' => $id],
        ['title' => $shopeTitle]
      );

      DB::table('calc_stores_in_malls')->where('id', $id)->update([
        'price' => $price,
        'visitors' => $visitors
      ]);

      if ($mall != 41 || $mall!= 42) {
        DB::table('calc_stores_in_malls')->insert([
          'mall' => $price,
          'store' => $id
        ]);
      }
```

But then I got the new error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::updateOrCreate()

How can I fix that?

Comment: `updateOrCreate` is an Eloquent function, which uses the models. You're bypassing that with `DB::table`. Why not just update the table names in your models?

Comment: BTW: You know that `($mall != 41 || $mall!= 42)` is always TRUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateOrCreate` is an Eloquent function.

The easiest way is to go through your models and update the table names by doing the following:

```
$protected $table = 'new_table_name';
```